# Calling an Image from WordPress Theme using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I'm trying to call a specific image from my WordPress theme when I'm in a certain category archive page. Keeps showing a blank image.

```
<?php 
if ( in_category('7') ) $image_name = '/images/logo.png';  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the absolute path to your theme directory by using `get_template_directory_uri()` so your code would look like this...

```
<?php 
if ( in_category('7') ) 
{ 
    $image_name = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png';  
}
?>
```

Hope that helps

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Check the category id. And what are you doing with `$image_name`?

```
<?php
if ( in_category('7') ) {
    $image_name = '/images/logo.png';
}
var_dump($image_name);
?>
```

Output should be `string(16) "/images/logo.png"`, otherwise `NULL` ($image_name is not set because the id @ `in_category` doesn't match.

```
<?php
if ( in_category('7') ) {
    $image = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png';
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';
}
?>
```